# unordered_map.emplace giving compiler time errors?

Tags: c++, c++11, dictionary, containers

I have this container as a member in a class:

```
std::unordered_map<std::string, Fruit> m_fruits;
```

I want to add a new element to it in the same class, I've tried 2 ways and both should work based on the example. (on emplace's page) But somewhere I made a mistake. (fruitName is a *const std::string&* )

```
m_fruits.emplace(fruitName, Fruit());
```

> Error C2660   'std::pair::pair': function does not take 2 arguments

```
m_fruits.emplace(std::make_pair(fruitName, Fruit()));
```

> Error C2440   '': cannot convert from 'initializer
>   list' to '_Mypair'

Fruit class:

```
class Fruit {

public:
    Fruit(); 
    Fruit(const Fruit& fruit) = delete;
    Fruit operator=(const Fruit& fruit) = delete;
    virtual ~Fruit();
};
```

**Update:**

I've found out that I should not have deleted the default copy constructor for fruit.

But I don't get it. Doesn't emplace is for constructing objects into container instead of creating an object outside of the container THEN copying it into the container?

> Inserts a new element into the container constructed **in-place** with the given args if there is no element with the key in the container.

Please somebody explain why I need a copy constructor to use this method.
Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a [MCVE] please? Just use a dummy declaration for `Fruit` like `struct Fruit {};`. `_Mypair` is suspicious also, it doesn't look like a standard c++ implementation.

Comment: how about `m_fruits[fruitName] = Fruit();`

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- `_Mypair` is definitely in the style of a widely used standard library implementation.

Comment: @Pete Well, silly naming though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ -- sigh.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what std::pair code does

```
_LIBCPP_INLINE_VISIBILITY _LIBCPP_CONSTEXPR_AFTER_CXX11
    pair(const _T1& __x, const _T2& __y)
         : first(__x), second(__y) {}
```

As per the above code, the argument is getting constructed from copy or move constructor. Hence you need either of one.

Fruit class doesn't have either copy constructor or move constructor defined. Here, **m_fruits.emplace(fruitName, Fruit())** the compiler generates temporary Fruit object which has to either copy constructed or move constructed inside the map. Since the Fruit class's copy constructor is deleted and doesn't have move constructor, it is giving compiler error. 
There are two ways you can get rid of this error

1) Introduce the move constructor

```
Fruit(Fruit && other) {
}
```

2) Or Don't delete the copy constructor, instead define the copy constructor

Fruit(const Fruit & other) {
   }

Here is the working snippet

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unordered_map>

class Fruit {
public:
    Fruit() {}
    Fruit(const Fruit& fruit) {
    }
    Fruit operator=(const Fruit& fruit) = delete;
    ~Fruit() {}
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_map<std::string, Fruit> m_fruits;

    m_fruits.emplace("apple", Fruit());
    m_fruits.emplace(std::make_pair("orange", Fruit()));
    for (const auto & e: m_fruits) {
       std::cout << "key=" << e.first << std::endl;
    }
}
```